# One form and Vector fields on a manifold in terms of local coordinates.

Tags: manifolds, coordinate-systems, differential-forms, vector-fields

Prove : $d$$\omega$$(V,W)$=$V \omega (W) - W \omega(V) -\omega([V,W])$ in local coordinates

where $\omega$ is a one-form and *V,W* are vector fields on a smooth manifold *M*.

I do not know how to represent $d$$\omega$$(V,W)$ in terms of local coordinates.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you.

Comment: In coordinates, $\omega=\omega_jdx^j$ (Einstein summation), so $d\omega=d\omega_j\wedge dx^j=\frac{\partial\omega_j}{\partial x^i}dx^i\wedge dx^j$.  From this you just evaluate on $V^j\partial_j, W^j\partial_j$.  The proof of the formula had already been answered, I just didn't see this portion of your question in the solution.